# Re-execute Callable if it fails

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, callable

Having an ExecutorService that executes a Callable that is supposed to be always running, what is the best implementation to relaunch it when an error happens?

Currently my source code looks something like this:

```
Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(new AlwaysOnlineCallable(config));
     try {
          future.get();
     } catch (Exception e) {
          //TODO thinking on execcuting the callable here
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

For what I've seen, cases like this are generally treated with runables.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit((Runnable) () -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    ...
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // log
                }
            }
        });
```

There doesn't seem to be any need for a `Callable` or a `Future`.

Comment: I had something like that. But something went wrong on the production site, and the runnable stopped and nobody noticed it until some days later. For what I've read, the Callable/Future is much better to catch and log errors. I was trying to implement a callable so I could relaunch it when something like this happens.

Comment: _"the Callable/Future is much better to catch and log errors"_ – this doesn't make sense.. any thread or runnable can catch exceptions and log errors.